# Angular 2 send data from component to service

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-services, angular-components

My target is to send data from Angular component to service and use service methods to work on it. Example:

```
export class SomeComponent {
    public data: Array<any> = MyData;
    public constructor(private myService: MyService) {
      this.myService.data = this.data;
    }
}
```

and service:

```
@Injectable()
export class TablePageService {
    public data: Array<any>;
    constructor() {
        console.log(this.data);
        // undefined
    }
}
```

Getting data is undefined. How to make it works?

Comment: The service constructor has already been run by the time you inject it into your component - since you don't initialize it, `data` is undefined at that time.

Comment: Before you can call a method on an object, it has to be constructed. Therefore your constructor is called and data is undefined. Then afterwards you access the member and modify the variable, but the constructor has been already called.

Comment: How can I fix that?

Comment: I would suggest you use methods to communicate between component and services. Also use subscriptions to make sure you receive the data when is available. Check documentation here, very useful: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: This is Typescript and not JavaScript, or?

Comment: Yes, typescript. I stand correct.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

An example if interaction between service and component could be:

**Service:**

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    myMethod$: Observable<any>;
    private myMethodSubject = new Subject<any>();

    constructor() {
        this.myMethod$ = this.myMethodSubject.asObservable();
    }

    myMethod(data) {
        console.log(data); // I have data! Let's return it so subscribers can use it!
        // we can do stuff with data if we want
        this.myMethodSubject.next(data);
    }
}
```

**Component1 (sender):**

```
export class SomeComponent {
    public data: Array<any> = MyData;

    public constructor(private myService: MyService) {
        this.myService.myMethod(this.data);
    }
}
```

**Component2 (receiver):**

```
export class SomeComponent2 {
    public data: Array<any> = MyData;

    public constructor(private myService: MyService) {
        this.myService.myMethod$.subscribe((data) => {
                this.data = data; // And he have data here too!
            }
        );
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

`MyService` is managing the `data`. You can still do stuff with `data` if you want, but is better to leave that to `Component2`.

Basically `MyService` receives `data` from `Component1` and sends it to whoever is subscribed to the method `myMethod()`.

`Component1` is sending `data` to the `MyService` and that's all he does.
`Component2` is subscribed to the `myMethod()` so each time `myMethod()` get called, `Component2` will listen and get whatever `myMethod()` is returning.

Comment: Where MyData in component2 came from?

Comment: I just took it from your code: `public data: Array<any> = MyData;`. It could also be declared as `public data = {};` for example, depends on the data type you are working with. I just wanted to keep it close to your example so it's more understandable for you.

Comment: Can I set two parameters? Let say two separate strings? Do I need two subjects and two Observables?

Comment: Send a second parameter in the same method. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp

Comment: Hi, I find your solution pretty accurate but I'm having a trouble in the receiver component, so let me ask you a question: the data returned from the subscribe must be an Array of even objects are fine?

Comment: @NadG Hello! Can be any type of data actually. You can send a Number, String, Object, Array...

Comment: @SrAxi, snap, I was hoping that the problem is the type of the data xD Well, good to know that it can be of any type. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: receiver component not getting the data

Answer (score 0):

There is a small issue with the receiver component in @SrAxi s reply as it can't subscribe to the service data. Consider using BehaviorSubject instead of Subject. It worked for me!

```
private myMethodSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>("");
```

Comment: `BehaviorSubject` is just a specialization of `Subject` that takes the latest value from the stream of data. The isse is probably not the type of `Subject` in your code, probably the issue is related to when you're subscribing.