# Angular pass parameter to parent component via @Output()

Tags: angular, typescript, events

I have two components, let's call them contianer and itemList. The itemList has clickable items, and I need to pass click events (including the index of the clicked item) to the container.

`itemList.ts`:

```
...
@Output()
itemClicked = new EventEmitter<number>();

@Output()
somethingElse = new EventEmitter<void>();

...
this.itemClicked.emit(index);
...
this.somethingElse.emit();
...
```

container.html:

```
...
<itemList (itemClicked)="itemClicked($index)"
          (somethingElse)="somethingElse()" ... >
  ...
</itemList>
...
```

container.ts:

```
...
itemClicked(observer: Observer<number>): void {
  // where do I get the index from ?
  console.debug('itemClicked( #' + index + ')');
}

somethingElse(observer: Observer<void>): void {
  console.debug('somethingElse()');
}
...
```

The question is in `container.ts`: where do I get the index from ?

The events from `somethingElse` are successfully passed to the container, so this can't be totally wrong. And in fact, this is the pattern I'm trying to build the itemClicked upon. But I could not change the signature of `itemClicked(...)` to a correct and working version.

Comment: I would use a shared service to send data (index in your case) from one component to another. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44066905/angular-2-send-data-from-component-to-service/44067238#44067238  I hope it can be helpful!

Comment: By the way you should name your @Output as verbs like `@Ouput() clicked` then you can access the event with a call back named "on<verb>" like `<itemList (clicked)="onClicked($event)">`.
It will make it easier for you to keep track of what is an output and what is a callback.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe your issue is in the container template where you're trying to pick up $index which doesn't exist. You should use $event.

```
...
<itemList (itemClicked)="itemClicked($event)"
      (somethingElse)="somethingElse()" ... >
  ...
</itemList>
```

...

That should allow you to access the value you emit from itemClicked. Then in your container component you can access the index in it's itemClicked function:

```
...
itemClicked(index: number): void {
  // the index will appear here
  console.debug('itemClicked( #' + index + ')');
}

somethingElse(): void {
  // You didn't pass any argument here
  console.debug('somethingElse()');
}
...
```

Note that the argument is the index itself and not an observable.

Hope that helps. Good luck.

Comment: OK, that works. And I just found out that I don't need the observer ... had picked a bad example from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Arguments that you receive in Output are called custom events. So you need to receive `$event` and that event will be of same type as you passed from child component.

```
<itemList (itemClicked)="itemClicked($event)"
          (somethingElse)="somethingElse()" ... >
  ...
</itemList>

itemClicked(index: number): void {
  console.debug('itemClicked( #' + index + ')');
}
```